# MYSQL subquery WHERE IN with count/having

Tags: mysql

I searched and found similar post to what I am trying to accomplish but not an exact solution. I have a table of grouped articles (articles that have information in common). I need to select articles from said table where there are at least 10 articles belonging to the group.

```
Group ID | Article ID | Posting Date
------------------------------------
| 1      | 1234       | 2017-07-14
| 1      | 5678       | 2017-07-14
| 1      | 9000       | 2017-07-14
| 2      | 8001       | 2017-07-14
| 2      | 8002       | 2017-07-14
------------------------------------

SELECT `groupid`, `article_id`, `publish_date`
FROM `article_group`
WHERE `groupid` IN ( SELECT `groupid`, count(`groupid`) as cnt
               FROM `article_group`
               WHERE date(`publish_date`) = '2017-07-14'
               group by `groupid`
               having cnt > 10
               order by cnt desc
               )
```

I understand the sub-query should just return the one column, but how do I accomplish this with the count and having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.  You should only be selecting one column in the subquery and the `ORDER BY` is not necessary:

```
SELECT `groupid`, `article_id`, `publish_date`
FROM `article_group`
WHERE `groupid` IN (SELECT `groupid`
                    FROM `article_group`
                    WHERE date(`publish_date`) = '2017-07-14'
                    GROUP BY `groupid`
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
                   )
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Gordon. I knew there was a simple solution.